# why UpdatePanel & UpdateProgress in asp.net page is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I use this UpdatePanel & UpdateProgress:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                Please Wait...
                <img alt="" src="../images/forDesign/loading.png" />
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="selectFile" AllowMultiple="true" />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload" runat="server" OnClick="Upload" />
                <asp:Label ID="LabelUploadFiles" runat="server" Visible="false" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I when click btnUpload,in addition to execute the Upload(), page_load() is execute too :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see here that within the asynchronous postback trigger, you have mentioned only the control but you have not mentioned any event upon which the update of the contents in the panel should happen.

Mention some event like Click and the asynchronous update should happen instead of a total page postback.